# Kibana Timelion error issues

Tags: kibana

I have used Timelion to generate Time series data. However, I have come across with errors when using split function.

This is my query without split `.es(index='cpu-*',metric='avg:CPU(%)').mvavg(1,left)` It runs fine and did generate chart. 
However, when it comes to splitting `.es(index='cpu-*', split=Hostname:5,metric='avg:CPU(%)').mvavg(1,left)`. It gives me the error of `Timelion: Error: in cell #1: Request Timeout after 30000ms.`

What could be the causes for that? I could not find what is wrong with my query